# List array into Javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list

**Goal:**

Pass the following tweet to visualization tool and display tweet on the UI.

**Setup:**

I'm getting the following '*List*' on my UI. I just want to convert this list to javascript array *(so that I can pass it to Visualization tools)*. I have concat'd `'qqq'` for end of every field to identify where it ends.

**Tweet:**

```
[*high-pitched yelp* http://t.co/qaluND2Lu3qqq, neutralqqq, 0qqq,
 I checked in at Starbucks on #Yelp http://t.co/8wRVos8STjqqq, negativeqqq, -0.159316qqq,
 i would like to thank yelp for not helping me find any club around santa monica that plays progressive edm / progressive tranceqqq, positiveqqq, 0.372338qqq,
 Nice long bar table &amp; upstairs option (@ Social Kitchen &amp; Brewery) on #Yelp http://t.co/uhQB003NTiqqq, positiveqqq, 0.567625qqq]
```

**Question:**
How do I split by `'qqq'` and then put it in a javascript array?

I have tried doing the following:

```
var str = "*high-pitched yelp* http://t.co/qaluND2Lu3qqq, neutralqqq, 0qqq";
var res = str.split("qqq");
```

But the method adds more one comma (,) at the end of every qqq. I'm confused.

Can someone help?

Comment: I don't see any problems here, you split on `qqq`, at this point you already have an array of strings. And the comma comes after every `qqq` in your string, so its normal that you see the comma in the result.

Comment: The argument to `split` is the separator **between** elements. So if you put `qqq` at the end, it means there's an empty element after it.

Comment: @Hatsjoem if I use "qqq" as seperator this is the output 
`*high-pitched yelp* http://t.co/qaluND2Lu3,, neutral,, 0,` (two commas)

Comment: The first comma is the seperator...

Comment: @Hatsjoem thank you. Yep but is it possible that I can split that huge string into three multiple arrays? Because, I just want to pass the third argument(score) to a heat map and the first argument (sentiment) to a pie chart and first argument (tweet) to display. Can I have it in different arrays?

Answer (score -2):

## Update 2

It might be best to just build a new clean array, without any undefined values.

```
var str = "*high-pitched yelp* http://t.co/qaluND2Lu3qqq, neutralqqq, 0qqq",
    myArray = str.split('qqq'),
    newArray = new Array();

for ( i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++ ) { // Assuming array is built starting with the key 0
    // Denote any array element that is undefined, or nonsensical white-space
    if ( myArray[i] !== "" && myArray[i] !== undefined && myArray[i] !== " " ) {
        newArray.push(myArray[i]);
    }
}

myArray = newArray;

console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: What's the difference? single and double quotes are equivalent in Javascript.

Comment: `str.split('qqq');` is the same as `str.split("qqq");`

Comment: Still have a syntax error in that splice and the indexOf is incorrect

Comment: Also you want `=== ""` not undefined

Comment: Sticky keyboard, sorry.

Comment: @WASasquatch `"" != undefined` and undefined isn't what you want to be comparing to. Your method produces `["*high-pitched yelp* http://t.co/qaluND2Lu3", ", neutral", ", 0", ""]` which is the exact same as ops

Comment: Aha you are right, probably best to just build a new array.

Comment: Could you please enlighten me? I'm really confused here. I just want to pass the **third** argument(score) to a heat map and the first argument (sentiment) to a pie chart and first argument (tweet) to display. Can I have it in different arrays? Thanks again!

Comment: Well if you need to preserve the array name you can rewrite the array with `myArray = newArray;` (after the `for()` loop.) all this does is remove values that have no value. For instance, the last element in your array.

Comment: I do need to preserve "0" sentiment because I think they count when we display them on a heatmap isn't it? I will try your code and get back THANK YOU! :). IF someone has any suggestions, please do let me know. I am a novice in Javascript and *would really appreciate your help*

Comment: @WASasquatch one question, in your example you have mentioned array input in the form of `"one","two","","four",undefined,"six"` but my output is little different. (it does not have ""). How can I push my tweets into `myArray`?

Comment: @DarkKnight That is an example of an array that has undefined values. You would provide it your array variable after you use `split('qqq');` to get your array. Something like `var myArray = str.split('qqq');` where `str` is your oriiginal string that needs splitting. This will remove your last array result with no value that creates the extra `, `